# How to convert row values to coulmn values in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have an excel with 10 rows and 20 coulmns but i want a new excel in which rows values in coulmn values

Answer (score 4):

Copy the values in the rows and then go to Edit, Paste Special and then tick the "Transpose" option.

Comment: My pleasure. Could you mark this as the answer please? It increases my rep. Thanks.